# How can we read the electricity usage from the Electricity Meters in Android?

Tags: android, energysmart

I'm an Android enthusiastic. I'm thinking of a eco-friendly app that awares the user about the electricity consumption they had made so far. So, I need some way to measure the electricity usage from the Electricity Meters. Most of the apps that I have browsed and used from Android market required me to enter the electricity usage manually which is kind of hectic and discouraging aspect of such apps. I want to automate that part and improve such apps. Any idea, Android Folks? Any suggestion, Android Guru?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_meter_reading there are many different types and likely proprietary implementations of the protocol used by these wireless meters.

Some likely even include encrypted or checksum verified protocols which would further prevent reading the data.

It's a good idea, but without official support from the companies supplying the meter reading technology you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could make the users take a picture of the meter. Then you could analyse the image...

Comment: enobayram, 
I've actually thought about this idea but I was expecting some easier approach than this.But thanx anyway...!

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at ioio ?

You may be able to interface it with a meter, if you have a way of converting the signal from a meter so the ioio can read it you should be able to make the app.

I am currently working on a project that implements this but a bit differently using a watt meter and amp meter

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10748